# Python Nested Lists: Referenced vs. Copied/Created Elements

Tags: python, arrays, memory, copy, memory-address

Python Nested Lists: Referenced vs. Copied/Created Elements

Hey there,

I'm struggling to understand when Python nested lists reference elements and when they copy or create them. For instance, this code creates a new list:

```py
foo = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(10)]
```

But this code references the list elements:

```py
foo = [[[0] * 3] * 5 for _ in range(10)]
```

Can anyone explain the difference between these two cases?

Unexpected Behavior with Python Nested Lists

I was working with Python nested lists and encountered some unexpected behavior. I tried creating a 2D list using the following code:

```py
foo = [[[0] * 3] * 5 for _ in range(10)]
```

I expected this to create a new list with 10 rows and 5 columns, all initialized to 0. However, when I tried to modify an element in the list using the following code:

```py
foo[0][1][0] = 1
```

I found that it modified multiple elements in the list instead of just one. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = [x for _ in range(y)]
```

creates a list of y unique elements of x.

```
list_ = [x] * y
```

creates a list of y references to x.

If you modify any of the elements in the former, it will only modify that element.

If you modify any of the elements in the latter, it will modify all of the created elements.

Here's a specific example:

```
list_ = [[1]] * 5
list2_ = [[1] for _ in range(5)]
for l in list_:
    l[0] += 1
    print(list_)

print('\n')

for l in list2_:
    l[0] += 1
    print(list2_)
```

Output:

```
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
[[4], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
[[5], [5], [5], [5], [5]]
[[6], [6], [6], [6], [6]]

[[2], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
[[2], [2], [1], [1], [1]]
[[2], [2], [2], [1], [1]]
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [1]]
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

This occurs because in list_ the variables are copied by reference, whereas in list2_, the variables are copied by value.

See: https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/